# Neo4j 3.x unmanaged extension slf4j issue

Tags: logging, neo4j, slf4j, graph-databases

I've converted my neo4j unmanaged extension to Neo4j 3.0.2. Now when I'm starting neo4j server I'm getting error below (neo4j.log):

```
WARN  FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList@26e74145[o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@6f4821f9{/,null,AVAILABLE}, o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@457192e2{/kastr,null,STARTING}, o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@15a93e18{/db/manage,null,null}, o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@188dddd2{/db/data,null,null}, o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47c4aef{/browser,jar:file:/C:/apps/neo4j-v3/lib/neo4j-browser-1.1.6.jar!/browser,null}, o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2a15f470{/,null,null}]:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger; Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutFieldsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:204)

...

WARN  FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5dd52c54: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger; Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutFieldsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:204)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:116)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)

ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Lorg/slf4j/Logger; Starting Neo4j failed: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
```

I'm using slf4j for logging internally.

How logging should be configured now? Could anyone advise.

**UPDATE**

In order to successfully start neo4j server I added three dependencies to pom.xml for `slf4j-api`, `logback-core` and `logback-classic`, plus copied packages jar files into `neo4j\lib` folder.

Now server starts without errors and extension loads and works fine. But all extension logging goes into `neo4j.log`.

In terms of logging configuration I have a logback.xml in `conf` folder as before, but it looks like it's been ignored.

Logback.xml for the reference is

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="EXTENSIONS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <file>logs/extensions.log</file>
         <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/extensions.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>25</maxHistory>
         </rollingPolicy>
         <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %-5level [%logger{15}]: %message%n</pattern>
         </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="EXTENSIONS"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of slf4j-api and which binding are you using?

Comment: @ceki self4j-api  1.7.7

Answer (score 0):

What is written to neo4j.log and debug.log ?

You can also add the slf4j dependency in your exension pom.xml

Care that the version is the same as the neo4j's pom :

For Neo4j 3.0.2

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can download the artifact and put it in the `lib` directory of neo4j.

Comment: I have slf4j dependency in pom.xml. Added slf4 package jar to neo4j lib as well with no luck. still getting the same error. I updated question with stack trace snapshot from neo4j.log. no errors in debug.log btw.